# Python Data science beginner function question

Tags: python, function

I'm prepping for a Data science bootcamp and know nothing about coding. Im stuck on this lab im doing right now.

so I have this list:

```
travel_destinations = ['argentina', 'mexico', 'italy', 'finland', 'canada', 'croatia']
```

I need to write a function called number_of_destinations that returns the number of destinations in the list travel_destinations.

Here's my code:

```
def number_of_destinations(travel_destinations):
    x = len(travel_destinations)
    print (x)
```

Which returns:

```
<function __main__.number_of_destinations(travel_destinations)>
```

Ive tried so many different approaches and python just keeps spitting out "yes this is a function" basically. Can anyone help me figure out what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, try using the `return` statement.

Comment: all we can see in your code is a function we need to see how your calling the function

Comment: The output you're getting is what you would see if you did `print(number_of_destinations)` instead of `print(number_of_destinations(travel_destinations))`

Comment: Try the functions section of the python tutorial. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

To call a function you need to add brackets to its name (and some parameters in the brackets, if the function takes parameters). Otherwise, as you have seen, Python just lets you know that you have entered the name of a function.

```
def my_function():
    return "hello"

>>> my_function
<function __main__.my_function()>
>>> my_function()
'hello'
```

Even though your bootcamp supposedly requires no coding knowledge, you should probably try to work through the examples in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Thank you! that worked. you guys helped me get unstuck and I appreciate it

Comment: +10 for being the only answer to explain why the user was getting that output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't passing data to the function.

```
def number_of_destinations(destinations): 
    x = len(travel_destinations) 
    print (x)
    return x

travel_destinations = ['argentina', 'mexico', 'italy', 'finland', 'canada', 'croatia']
destinations_length = number_of_destinations(travel_destinations)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the result he's getting.

Comment: Didn't see OP's edit. Regardless this solution should work for him and address his issues

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def number_of_destinations(destinations):
    return len(travel_destinations)

travel_destinations = ['argentina', 'mexico', 'italy', 'finland', 'canada', 'croatia']

print(number_of_destinations(travel_destinations))
```

Comment: that worked, but when I try to call the function number_of_destinations it simply returns <function __main__.number_of_destinations(destinations)> instead of "6". But if I just run the line of code you posted above it work and returns '6'

Comment: That is correct. When you call the function `number_of_destinations` without parameter `travel_destinations` it returns information about the function (it is a function of `__main__` i.e. the script your are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass default argument in fucntion.

```py
travel_destinations = ['argentina', 'mexico', 'italy', 'finland', 'canada', 'croatia']
def number_of_destinations(destinations=travel_destinations):
    return len(travel_destinations)
print(number_of_destinations())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the function can be more generalized to return the length of a list. The if condition to check whether the passed argument is of type list is optional. The condition can be part of the function as well.

```
def func(lst):
    return (len(lst))

travel_destinations = ['argentina', 'mexico', 'italy', 'finland', 'canada', 'croatia']

if type(travel_destinations=='list'):
   x = func(travel_destinations)
   print (x)
else:
    print ('invalid input type')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def number_of_destinations(destinations):
    return len(travel_destinations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe shall have two columns i.e. `travel_destinations` and `num_of_destinations`.

So your code shall contain function given below:

```
def number_destination(name_travel_destination):
   x = df[ df['travel_destination']=="name_travel_destination"]
   ans = df[x][num_of_destination]
   return ans
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function doesn't return anything because you're missing a return statement. The print function outputs to the terminal but does not return, so you need to swap that out.

```
def number_of_destinations(travel_destinations):
    x = len(travel_destinations)
    return x
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the result he's getting.

Comment: The post was edited after I answered, this may help OP anyway

Comment: The only edits I can see just fixed the formatting, they didn't change the question.

Comment: Originally there was no
`<function __main__.number_of_destinations(travel_destinations)`
after
"Which returns"
So I assumed OP meant it just wasn't returning anything.

Comment: Yeah, that was a formatting problem. He didn't put it in a code block, so that was treated as an HTML tag because of `<>`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use count variable and loop through the list and print the number of values in it
using count_city variable

```
def num_of_destinations(travel_destinations):
city_count=0
for city in travel_destinations:
    city_count+=1
print(city_count)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.